# How to add a thread safe method to synchronizedList？

Tags: java

```java
public class ListHelper {
    private final List<String> list= Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    public boolean putIfAbsent(String x) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" start putIfAbsent");
        synchronized (list){
            boolean absent=!list.contains(x);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (absent){
                System.out.println("add前hashcode: "+list.hashCode());
                list.add(x);
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" end putIfAbsent");
            return absent;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ListHelper helper = new ListHelper();
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        String a = "a";
        new Thread(()->{
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-"+helper.putIfAbsent(a));
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        },"A").start();
        new Thread(()->{
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-list.add() start");
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-"+helper.list.add(a));
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        },"B").start();
        countDownLatch.await();
        for (Object o : helper.list) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it was right to use `list` as a lock, but the output of the program surprised me.
The program output looks like this:

```
A start putIfAbsent
B-list.add() start
A end putIfAbsent
A-true
B-true
a
a
```

`list` doesn't seem to be mutually exclusive

Comment: I don't see where in your output that would indicate that your lock didn't work. Thread A got the lock first, then B.

Comment: Thank for your answer,This is exactly the right output.I seemed a little confused yesterday.